# How to make webpage viewable to users logged in with Parse?

Tags: javascript, html, authentication, parse-platform

I've built a homepage where users can login/register using parseSDK. That works at the moment. The second page I've made is a dashboard (dashboard.html) which should be viewable to only users that login. At the moment, anyone can do ... http://mywebsite.com/dashboard.html and see the webpage.

How can I set it up in such a way such that every time an user (not logged in at the time) goes to that URL, it will take them to index.html to login?

Comment: I have not used parse.com for logins in a web setting, however, generally speaking, you should end up with some kind of session or cookie data from the login process, the presence of which you can check for prior to displaying the secured page. From a very cursory look at their API doc, you may want to look at: https://www.parse.com/docs/js/guide#sessions and the "Roles" section which follows it.

Answer (score 0):

Check for `Parse.User.current()` in your javascript code. This gives you the details of current logged in user. You can redirect to index.html or dashboard.html accordingly.